# Why do I get [WARNING]: running playbook inside collection

Tags: ansible, ansible-collections

I am trying to structure my re-usable ansible code in collections (roles, modules...) and I wanted to use the same strategy for playbooks.
Imagine a collection named `acme.cloud`.

In the root of the collection, I have the following files directory structure:

```
/docs
/meta
/playbooks
/playbooks/test.yml
/roles
galaxy.yml
README.md
```

Now when I run `ansible-plybook acme.cloud.test -i /someinventory` i get the warning:

```
[WARNING]: running playbook inside collection acme.cloud
```

The playbook runs fine but I am concerned about the warning, the reason about it, possible problems and side consequences.
I could not find any documentation state that playbooks are not allowed in collections

Any idea or comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a simple warning which was [added in 2020](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/e05c62547b3d547ffb433d1cf66e82b353f24262) when ansible learned to run playbooks from collections. I suppose this was a way to draw attention to developers/users that they were executing playbooks a bit differently than previously (e.g. no adjacent `library` folder for example).

Unfortunately at this stage, this warning cannot be silenced. But the good news is there's a [commit in devel branch on November 8 2022](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/4759590467faa23776f527e049a1686505339d4f) which moves that information display from a warning to a simple info you get when running ansible in verbose mode (`-v`). It makes a lot of sense since running from collections is now well spread with the latest versions.

This commit was pushed a day after [ansible-core 2.14 version was fixed in the git repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/520bb66f8ab6d53750f48f024287572962d975fa) and [released](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.14/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.14.rst#v2140). So I guess this feature will be available in ansible 2.14.1 (actually crafted in rc)